# How can two time columns in a pandas DataFrame be used to label rows in a reindexed DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, reindex

I have a DataFrame that features two time columns. I want to reindex or create a new DataFrame with an index that covers the total time of those columns and I want the times in those columns to be used to label rows in the reindexed or new DataFrame. How might this be done efficiently?

```
df = pd.read_csv("NBER_chronology.csv")# 
http://www.nber.org/cycles/NBER%20chronology.xlsx
df["Peak month"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Peak month"])
df["Trough month"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Trough month"])
df.tail()
```

[image]

The index could be defined in the following way:

```
pd.date_range(start = df["Trough month"].values[0], end = df["Trough month"].values[-1])
```

However, I feel that taking this route is a bit too manual.

Answer (score 0):

This sets the index as the difference between Trough dates as 'timespan'. Oddly does it in days, I bet you could change that if you wanted.

```
df = pd.read_csv("NBER_chronology.csv")#
#http://www.nber.org/cycles/NBER%20chronology.xlsx
df["Peak month"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Peak month"])
df["Trough month"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Trough month"])

# date of next row
after_df = pd.DataFrame(df['Trough month'].iloc[1:])
after_df.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
df['after'] = after_df

# column that contains difference 
df['timespan'] = df['after'] - df["Trough month"]
df['timespan'] = df['timespan'].shift(1)

# set index
df.set_index('timespan', inplace=True)
```